# What is the equivalent of VsCode's Auto Rename Tag in sublime text 3?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

In VsCode,using the extension **Auto Rename Tag**, if you edit the html opening tag, the closing html tag automatically changes, like

`<title>Document</title>`

`<ti>Document</ti>`

Is there any alternative to this **Auto Rename Tag** in **Sublime Text 3**?

Comment: If you have emmet installed: Cmd+Shift+K on mac, Ctrl+Shift+ on windows

Comment: @muhammad Iqbal, is there any way that it can be automatic?